# program shifts data to the right by 1

Tags: c#, winforms

My code below appends a period to the end of a character entered but each time it shifts the data by 1 extra space to the right. How would I get back that space? The program is very space sensitive

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stringToReplace = textBox1.Text;
        if (stringToReplace.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid string.");
            return;
        }
        if (stringToReplace.Length != 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid string that is 6 characters in length.");
            return;
        }
        OpenFileDialog filedialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = filedialog.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string filePath = filedialog.FileName;
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
                string line;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (counter == 0 && !line.Contains(stringToReplace+ "."))
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(stringToReplace, stringToReplace + ".");
                    }
                    counter++;
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
                file.Close();
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                string newFilename = filePath.Replace(ext, "-new" + ext);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newFilename, lines.ToArray());
                MessageBox.Show("Process is completed.");
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("We apologize but an error occured can you try again?");
            }
        }
    }
```

This screenshot shows how the file should look after the program executes:
[image]

The below screenshot shows how it looks how the initial program executes:

[image]

As you can see it shifted by one.

Comment: show your specific data and the desired output.

Comment: try to make a sample text example and your sample result. that's it

Comment: Isn't that what is technically done in the post?@reds

Comment: Well the first screenshot is different from the 2nd screenshot.. Notice the dot (.) after P12104? that's why on the 2nd screenshot it moved to the right by 1

Comment: @JCBorlagdan I know, that is what the program does. I want to somehow trim to get that one space back. That's what I am saying in my post

Comment: if you post the lines as monospace text instead of images, it's a bit easier to notice the difference. Maybe `line = line.Replace(stringToReplace+" ", stringToReplace + ".");` if the line always has space after the `stringToReplace`

Comment: @Slai that works, thank you